# Invalid false result expression in CASE WHEN T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exec, case-when

I am writing a query which unpivots the table. The issue is that based on the mapping file I would like to either input values as a constant or variable.

For example - if in mapping file the ExtDate is constant, e.g. ExtDate = '2017-12-31' I want to use this value (2017-12-31). However if ExtDate starts with 'Var' I would like to use variable values - e.g. when ExtDate = VarOpenDate, then I want to fulfill the column with values from column OpenDate. Below exemplary rows from MappingFile:

```
CREATE TABLE MappingFile (ColNum INT, Variable CHAR(50), IsUsed CHAR(50), ID CHAR(50), ExtDate CHAR(50), DataDate CHAR(50), ValueDate CHAR(50), Flag CHAR(50), Unit CHAR(50))
INSERT INTO MappingFile VALUES (1,  'ClientId', 'YES', 'VarAcctID', '2017-12-31', 'VarSigningDate', 'VarSigningDate', 'X', '')  
INSERT INTO MappingFile VALUES (2,  'ProductGroup', 'YES', 'VarAcctID', 'VarOpenDate', 'VarSigningDate', 'VarSigningDate', 'X', '')     
INSERT INTO MappingFile VALUES (3,  'ProductType', 'YES', 'VarAcctID',  'VarOpenDate', 'VarSigningDate', 'VarSigningDate', 'X', '')
```

In order to do this I wrote a code below (this is a simplification, as there are more columns and whole query is in the inserting while loop).

```
DECLARE @I INT = 2
DECLARE @COL CHAR(50)
DECLARE @ID CHAR(50)
DECLARE @EDT CHAR(50)
DECLARE @DDT CHAR(50)
DECLARE @DTS CHAR(50) = 'dataset_name'

SET @ID  = (SELECT ID        FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)
SET @EDT = (SELECT ExtDate   FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)
SET @DDT = (SELECT DataDate  FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)
SET @COL = (SELECT Variable  FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)

EXEC('
        SELECT ''' + @DTS + ''',
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(''' + @ID  + ''', 1, 3) = ''Var'' THEN ' + @ID  + ' ELSE ''' + @ID  + ''' END,
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(''' + @EDT + ''', 1, 3) = ''Var'' THEN ' + @EDT + ' ELSE ''' + @EDT + ''' END,
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(''' + @DDT + ''', 1, 3) = ''Var'' THEN ' + @DDT + ' ELSE ''' + @DDT + ''' END,
                ''' + @COL + ''',
                ' + @COL + '        
FROM ' + @DTS + '
        WHERE ' + @COL + ' IS NOT NULL
        ')
```

Unfortunately in case when ExtDate is constant string the query gives me an error. It is caused by the fact that the result expression:

```
THEN ' + @EDT + '
```

returns string which is not a name of column. This gives me an error, altough it shouldn't because if

```
SUBSTRING(''' + @ID  + ''', 1, 3) <> ''Var''
```

then the result of the case is

```
' ELSE ''' + @DDT + '''
```

which is not a column name, but a constant string.

Comment: Instead of executing your dynamic SQL straight off the bat, put it into a variable (for example called `@SQL` with the datatype `nvarchar(MAX)`), then use `PRINT @SQL;`. You'll probably very quickly see what the problem is. I'd also recommend the use of `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: Another hint might be to change `THEN ' + @EDT + ' ELSE` to `THEN ''' + @EDT + ''' ELSE` - even ich the variables content is recognized, a code like `SELECT 2018-03-15` will fail.

Comment: On a different note, did you try running your `CREATE` and `INSERT` statement? All 3 fail with `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`. Well done for trying, but when supplying DDL and consumable sample data, check that it works first. :). *You might also want to provide some declaration for your variables in your second statement as well.*

Comment: @Larnu thank you, just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have dynamically built a query that cannot parse.

Consider the test query below:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    Col int
    );

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1);

SELECT CASE 
 WHEN 1=0 THEN NoSuch ELSE 'Hi' END
 FROM @T;
```

Run this, and it results in

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Invalid column name 'NoSuch'.

Because even though the CASE doesn't execute the `THEN` and skips to the `ELSE`, the parser doesn't know that in advance and checks to make sure `NoSuch` is a column.   If it isn't, it rejects the query before it even tries to run it.

One solution is to check your variables OUTSIDE of the dynamic string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tab Alleman I managed to find the solution. The phenomenon regarding parser is exactly true, therefore I had to check the variables outside the EXEC command.

Below find the code which works:

```
DECLARE @I INT = 2
DECLARE @COL CHAR(50)
DECLARE @ID CHAR(50)
DECLARE @EDT CHAR(50)
DECLARE @DDT CHAR(50)
DECLARE @DTS CHAR(50) = 'dataset_name'

SET @ID  = (SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(ID       , 1, 3) = 'Var' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(ID       , LEN(ID        ) - 3))) WHEN ID            = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONCAT('''', LTRIM(RTRIM(ID       )), '''') END FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)
SET @EDT = (SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(ExtDate  , 1, 3) = 'Var' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(ExtDate  , LEN(ExtDate   ) - 3))) WHEN ExtDate       = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONCAT('''', LTRIM(RTRIM(ExtDate  )), '''') END FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)
SET @DDT = (SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DataDate , 1, 3) = 'Var' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(DataDate , LEN(DataDate  ) - 3))) WHEN DataDate      = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE CONCAT('''', LTRIM(RTRIM(DataDate )), '''') END FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)
SET @COL = (SELECT Variable  FROM MappingFile WHERE ColNum = @I)

EXEC('
    SELECT ''' + @DTS + ''',
            ' + @ID  + ',
            ' + @EDT + ',
            ' + @DDT + ',
            ''' + @COL + ''',
            ' + @COL + '        
    FROM ' + @DTS + '
    WHERE ' + @COL + ' IS NOT NULL
    ')
```